# PHP - PHPUnit - Test Ability to Secure a Filelock

Tags: php, phpunit, flock

I am working on updating unit tests for my core library, and came across a scenario regarding filelocks (flock), and wanted to see how others implemented these types of unit tests.

Basically I have a utlity File class which will write contents to a file:

```
class CoreLib_Api_File_Package
{
    public static function write(array $options)
    {
        ...

        if (!$file->flock(LOCK_EX)) {
            throw new CoreLib_Api_Exception('Unable to obtain lock on file');
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

And my unit test looks like:

```
public function testWriteException_UnableToSecureLock()
{
    $this->touchFile($this->destFileUri);

    $file = new SplFileObject($this->destFileUri, CoreLib_Api_File::MODE_WRITE);

    $file->flock(LOCK_EX);

    CoreLib_Api_File_Package::write(array('fileUri' => $this->destFileUri, 'content' => $this->testContent, 'mode' => CoreLib_Api_File::MODE_WRITE));
}
```

As you can see from the test code I am putting an explicit lock on `$this->destFileUri` before I make the API call to the `write()` method. What I would expect is that the exception `throw new CoreLib_Api_Exception('Unable to obtain lock on file');` to be thrown. Instead, my unit test just hangs indefinitely.

What would be the proper way to test whether a file has a lock?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php#95257) on the `flock` [docs page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php).

Essentially, `flock` will pause execution until it is able to obtain the lock. Take the following code, which is similar to your situation above:

```
$file = 'file.txt';

$first = fopen($file, "w");
flock($first, LOCK_EX);

$second = fopen($file, "w");

# Your script will pause on the next line until timeout
# due to the inability to obtain a lock.
flock($second, LOCK_EX);
```

However, you can obtain non-blocking locks like this:

```
flock($file, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB);
```

I am not sure if there are negative implications to locking files this way. Also, *while the docs say `LOCK_NB` does not work on Windows, I just tested it and it worked on my machine*. So, you could do something like this in your `CoreLib_Api_File_Package::write` method:

```
class CoreLib_Api_File_Package
{
    public static function write(array $options)
    {
        if ( ! $file->flock(LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB))
        {
            throw new CoreLib_Api_Exception('Unable to obtain lock on file');
        }
    }
}
```

Your current test should pass as-written. Other than that, I can't think of anything.

**Edit:** They should pass as long as you are telling `PHPUnit` to expect the `CoreLib_Api_Exception` exception (just pointing it out because you didn't have it in your example).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I read that post too, was just curious how others got around this issue. I'm going to keep the question open for a few days to see if I can other answers, if not I'll accept this one.